# Keras CNN model with a wrong ROC curve and low accuracy

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am learning to write CNNs in Keras on Kaggle using one of the datasets I found there.

The link to my notebook is

https://www.kaggle.com/vj6978/brain-tumor-vimal?scriptVersionId=16814133

The code, the dataset and the ROC curve are available at the link. The ROC curve itself looks as if the model is simply making guesses rather than a learned prediction.

The testing accuracy also seems to peak at around 60% to 70% only which is quiet low. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vimal James

Comment: Please add code to the question so its self-contained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your last activation should be sigmoid instead of softmax.

UPDATE :

Just forked your kernel on Kaggle and modifying as follows gives better results :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), input_shape = data_set.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid")) # Last activation should be sigmoid for binary classification

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

This gave the following results :

```
rain on 204 samples, validate on 23 samples
Epoch 1/15
204/204 [==============================] - 2s 11ms/step - loss: 2.8873 - acc: 0.6373 - val_loss: 0.8000 - val_acc: 0.8261
Epoch 2/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.7292 - acc: 0.7206 - val_loss: 0.6363 - val_acc: 0.7391
Epoch 3/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.4731 - acc: 0.8088 - val_loss: 0.5417 - val_acc: 0.8261
Epoch 4/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3605 - acc: 0.8775 - val_loss: 0.6820 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 5/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2986 - acc: 0.8529 - val_loss: 0.8356 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 6/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2151 - acc: 0.9020 - val_loss: 0.7592 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 7/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.1305 - acc: 0.9657 - val_loss: 1.2486 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 8/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0565 - acc: 0.9853 - val_loss: 1.2668 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 9/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0426 - acc: 0.9853 - val_loss: 1.4674 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 10/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0141 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.7379 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 11/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0063 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.7232 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 12/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0023 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.8291 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 13/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0014 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.9164 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 14/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 8.6263e-04 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.8946 - val_acc: 0.8696
Epoch 15/15
204/204 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 6.8785e-04 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.9596 - val_acc: 0.8696
Test loss: 3.079359292984009
Test accuracy: 0.807692289352417
```

Comment: This is more suited as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: Hi @Coder, I am not able to enter a comment on the original post... My reputation is not high enough.

Comment: Hi @OliverG .. I tried the Sigmoid activation at the last layer, however I still get the same ROC curve. I'm not sure that was the issue thought :/

Comment: @james, I updated my answer with the actual tested code. hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @OlivierG. ... I got the code working however I am still getting a very steep ROC that is not smooth at all. Could you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `softmax` activation with a single neuron, this will **always** produce constant 1.0 output, due to the normalization used in softmax, so it makes no sense. For binary classification you have to use the `sigmoid` activation with a single output neuron.